# How can I delete a field from a Sitecore template?

Tags: sitecore

I've tried the following:

Deleting the fields Name and Type, saving the template (red square in screenshot)

Selecting the field on the left tree and pressing delete (green in screenshot)

Using the Builder Options menu and pressing Remove button (blue in screenshot)

[image]

After any of these actions, the field would magically reappear. I've also tried renaming the field and the old name comes back. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I thought it would be the easiest thing to delete a property.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally on the web database and a publish is putting it back?

Comment: How/when does it re-appear?  right after saving/deleting?

Comment: Are you using ucommerce or other commerce platform ?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber i am using ucommerce, this is actually an template for an item from ucommerce

Comment: Important detail missing. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Ucommerce you need to delete from product definition field not from Sitecore templates.

UCommerce is using a data provider to bring product fields from ucommerce db to Sitecore db.

That's the reason why fields are reaper in Sitecore.

Please check here how to add and delete product definition fields : http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v6.9/getting-started/catalog-foundation/product-definitions.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the template after making these changes. Use Ctrl+S or click Save in the Home ribbon.

To remove a field, you can also right click > delete in the Content Tree.